# JQUERY Append issue when working with <UL> <LI> when the <LI> has inner DIV Structures

Tags: jquery, html-lists, sharepoint-online

Ok, so here goes:

I am having a not so odd JQUERY issues. At least I think I am. My base HTML code is a fancy `<DIV>` `<UL>` `<LI>` structure (shown below). Each LI has it's own inner `DIV` structure though as well.

These are all styles using the Flexslider solution (a few years old). It works great when I just use it inline, but I am trying to convert this to JQUERY using a SP List.

A quick note: This is O365 SP not On-Prem

Some background on what works:

1. The list data from SharePoint is arriving just fine and when I do simple JQUERY `.HTML(myHtml)` it displays on the page properly.
2. The base Flexslider works just fine when I just use inline code without JQUERY for dummy testing.

What does not work is when I try to apply the data to the `<LI>` structure using either `.HTML(myHtml)` or `.APPEND(myHTML)`. My guess it is because the `<LI>` structure has multiple inner `DIV` and somehow I have the append logic wrong for that.

Here is what the HTML should look like (with Sample Data)

```html
<div class="page-content-wrapper">
  <div class="flexslider carousel">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <div class="fleximage lcol">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
          <a href="#"><img src="/DoingGood.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="flexcaption rcol">
          <div class="headline">TITLE!</div>
          <div class="teaser">BLURB</div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code works when inserted just like that into the page. The problem occurs when I try to use the JQUERY below.

```js
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
  var listItemInfo = '';
  var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
  while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += '<li><div class=\"fleximage lcol\"><img src=\"' + oListItem.get_item('ImageURL') + '\"></div> <div class=\"flexcaption rcol\"> <div class=\"headline\">' + oListItem.get_item('Title')+'</div> <div class=\"teaser\"> ' + oListItem.get_item('Blurb') + '</div> </div></li> '; 
  }
  alert(listItemInfo);
  $(".slides").html(listItemInfo);
}
```

Essentially I get NO output when using this. The ALERT shows me my data , as expected. I am guessing it is because of the structure of '''DIV''' tags in the `LI` and I need a different output approach?

Here is a sample output from the ALERT Message for the listItemInfo variable:

````
<li>
<div class="fleximage lcol"><img src="./Lexington/SiteCollectionDocuments/DoingGood.jpg"/></div>
<div class="flexcaption rcol">
<div class="headline">Test Stephen!</div>
<div class="teaser"> ​test</div>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<div class="fleximage lcol"><img src="./Lexington/SiteCollectionDocuments/DoingGood.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="flexcaption rcol">
<div class="headline">Test 3 Steve</div>
<div class="teaser"> Tesst 4</div>
</div>
</li>```
````

Comment: Too much code. Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57509928/edit) then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] with a clear explanation of expected output - for example what is the `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` and what is the need for it and sp.js?

Comment: Assuming your sp query works as intended, there is no need for that code in your question, only the onQuerySucceeded with an example object. If you remove the rest of the code and leave just that and the HTML, we can better help you

Comment: I will try to trim it up a bit. ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js") is the library for jquery to work with SharePoint. All of that actually works. The issue seems to ultimately be $(".slides").html(listItemInfo); and how it renders the <LI> structure. I will try to minimize it a bit.

Comment: You don't need to escape double quote inside a string that's delimited with single quotes.

Comment: Do provide an example `collListItem`

Comment: @Andreas I assume he didn't actually have multiline strings, or the code wouldn't execute at all, and he says he's getting the alert.

Comment: If the nested DIVs work in the static HTML, there's no reason it wouldn't work when you add the HTML dyncamically.

Comment: It shouldn't affect the problem, but you're missing the `<a>` around the image.

Comment: This is easier to maintain: `listItemInfo.push(\`<li>
      <div class="fleximage lcol"><img src="${oListItem.get_item('ImageURL')}" /></div> 
      <div class="flexcaption rcol">
        <div class="headline">${oListItem.get_item('Title')}</div> 
        <div class="teaser">${oListItem.get_item('Blurb')}</div>
      </div>
    </li>\`) .....  $(".slides").html(listItemInfo.join(""));`

Comment: I would agree as well. I updated it with an example of the output of the listItemInfo...

Comment: Do you see the new HTML in the DOM inspector?

Comment: It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/9r2dp6zg/5/

Comment: Since it is SharePoint, could a postback be wiping anything? There are no form interactions, but the SP MasterPage does wrap up into a massive form, starting here:

<SharePoint:SharePointForm onsubmit="if (typeof(_spFormOnSubmitWrapper) != 'undefined') {return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();} else {return true;}" runat="server">
  
  <script type="text/javascript"> var submitHook = function () { return false; }; theForm._spOldSubmit = theForm.submit; theForm.submit = function () { if (!submitHook()) { this._spOldSubmit(); } }; </script>

Comment: And yes, I do see the HTML in the DOM. It is just not displaying on the page. If I inject the same HTML directly into the page, it works.

Comment: @Barmer You're absolutely right. I somehow missed the `alert` part... :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test demo which works in my online environment.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.2/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.2/flexslider.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myfunction, "sp.js");
        });
        function myfunction() {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Slider');

            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' +
                '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
            this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.load(collListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }
        function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
            var listItemInfo = '';
            var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                listItemInfo += '<li><div class=\"fleximage lcol\"><img src=\"' + oListItem.get_item('ImageURL').get_url() + '\"></div> <div class=\"flexcaption rcol\"> <div class=\"headline\">' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + '</div> <div class=\"teaser\"> ' + oListItem.get_item('Blurb') + '</div> </div></li> ';
            }
            //alert(listItemInfo);
            $(".slides").html(listItemInfo);
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                rtl: true,
                start: function (slider) {
                    $('body').removeClass('loading');
                }
            })
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    </script>
    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="flexslider" style="direction:rtl">
            <ul class="slides"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you doing that in the Master Page or as a Content Editor with a link to code in a  file, or as a code snippet web part?

Comment: Actually, you gave me the solution in a roundabout way.

I am using a customized flexslider and it is referenced in the MasterPage with JQUERY. For some reason when I was using a code snippet it wanted me to put the paths to those files again to make them work.

Once I did that it worked just fine. Odd....